# Repeat argument of macro for cleveref referencing (forcsvlist?)

Tags: enumitem, cleveref, etoolbox

This is a follow up question on [How to customize enumerate list with resuming numbering on second level using customize item command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/636802/how-to-customize-enumerate-list-with-resuming-numbering-on-second-level-using-cu). Now I am wondering how I can reference to the entries of my workpackages-list.

The crucial part seems to be repeating `\mylist:` for each of the argument of `\crcWP` to pass it to `\cref{...}`. Only `\crcWP{<hook(s)>}` should be needed to reference to a workpackage.

I am not sure how I can achieve this with e.g. `forcsvlist`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[compress]{cleveref}

% ==== List for Workpackages
%
\newlist{workpackages}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[workpackages,1]{
  label={WP\,\arabic*:},
  ref = {\arabic*},
  resume
}

\setlist[workpackages,2]{
  ref={\theworkpackagesi\alph*},
  label={WP\,\theworkpackagesi\alph*:}
}

\crefname{workpackagesi}{\bfseries WP}{\bfseries WPs}
\creflabelformat{workpackagesi}{#2#1#3}
\crefname{workpackagesii}{\bfseries WP}{\bfseries WPs}
\creflabelformat{workpackagesii}{#2#1#3}



\providecommand{\mylist}{}

\newcommand{\crcWP}[1]{\cref{\mylist:#1}}
%                           ^repeatThis^
%\forcsvlist{\crcWP}{\crcWP}

\newcommand{\crcItem}[1]{\item\label{\mylist:#1}}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\def\mylist{abc}
\begin{workpackages}
  \crcItem{A} some text
  \crcItem{B} some text
  \begin{workpackages}
  \crcItem{B1} some text
  \crcItem{B2} some text
\end{workpackages}
\crcItem{C} some text
  \crcItem{D} some text
  \begin{workpackages}
  \crcItem{D1} some text
  \crcItem{D2} some text
  \end{workpackages}
\end{workpackages}

\cref{\mylist:A,\mylist:B}
% that should be the same as
% \crcWP{A,B}

\cref{\mylist:C}
% that should be the same as
% \crcWP{C}

% ==== new section
\def\mylist{def} %% <<<< difference!
\restartlist{workpackages}
\begin{workpackages}
  \crcItem{A} some text
  \crcItem{B} some text
  \begin{workpackages}
  \crcItem{B1} some text
  \crcItem{B2} some text
  \end{workpackages}
  \crcItem{C} some text
  \crcItem{D} some text
  \begin{workpackages}
  \crcItem{D1} some text
  \crcItem{D2} some text
  \end{workpackages}
\end{workpackages}
\cref{\mylist:B1,\mylist:C}
% that should be the same as
% \crcWP{B1,C}

\cref{\mylist:D2}
% that should be the same as
% \crcWP{D2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `expl3` that's more flexible than `etoolbox`. The main part is

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\crcWP}{m}
 {
  \clist_clear:N \l__lukascb_wp_refs_clist
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 } { \clist_put_right:Nn \l__lukascb_wp_refs_clist { \mylist-##1 } }
  \exp_args:NV \cref \l__lukascb_wp_refs_clist
 }
```

An auxiliarly clist is cleared, then populated using the input, but adding `\mylist-` in front. Then the new list is passed to `\cref`.

Complete example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[compress]{cleveref}

% ==== List for Workpackages
%
\newlist{workpackages}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[workpackages,1]{
  label={WP\,\arabic*:},
  ref = {\arabic*},
  resume
}

\setlist[workpackages,2]{
  ref={\theworkpackagesi\alph*},
  label={WP\,\theworkpackagesi\alph*:}
}

\crefname{workpackagesi}{\bfseries WP}{\bfseries WPs}
\creflabelformat{workpackagesi}{#2#1#3}
\crefname{workpackagesii}{\bfseries WP}{\bfseries WPs}
\creflabelformat{workpackagesii}{#2#1#3}



\newcommand{\mylist}{}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\crcWP}{m}
 {
  \clist_clear:N \l__lukascb_wp_refs_clist
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 } { \clist_put_right:Nn \l__lukascb_wp_refs_clist { \mylist-##1 } }
  \exp_args:NV \cref \l__lukascb_wp_refs_clist
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\crcItem}[1]{\item\label{\mylist-#1}}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\def\mylist{abc}
\begin{workpackages}
  \crcItem{A} some text
  \crcItem{B} some text
  \begin{workpackages}
  \crcItem{B1} some text
  \crcItem{B2} some text
\end{workpackages}
\crcItem{C} some text
  \crcItem{D} some text
  \begin{workpackages}
  \crcItem{D1} some text
  \crcItem{D2} some text
  \end{workpackages}
\end{workpackages}

\crcWP{A,B}

\crcWP{C}

% ==== new section
\renewcommand\mylist{def} %% <<<< difference!
\restartlist{workpackages}
\begin{workpackages}
  \crcItem{A} some text
  \crcItem{B} some text
  \begin{workpackages}
  \crcItem{B1} some text
  \crcItem{B2} some text
  \end{workpackages}
  \crcItem{C} some text
  \crcItem{D} some text
  \begin{workpackages}
  \crcItem{D1} some text
  \crcItem{D2} some text
  \end{workpackages}
\end{workpackages}

\crcWP{B1,C}

\crcWP{D2}

\end{document}
```

I had to change the colon into `-`, because `:` is special in `expl3` code, but that should be of no concern, as you don't use explicitly the labels.

As a sidenote: doing `\providecommand{\mylist}{}` is wrong: you want to ensure that the command you're using is not existing; otherwise you'd run into problems when you redefine it.

[image]

Comment: expl3 is so powerful, it seems worth to take a closer look at its syntax... Thank you very much!